# Can you prevent 3D touch on an <img> but not tap and hold to save?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, safari, mobile-safari

On `<img>` tags on iOS mobile Safari, you can tap and hold on an image to bring up a Save Sheet. You can also 3D touch to pop/peek it.

Can you prevent 3D touch while maintaining the tap and hold functionality?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42160260/2873331 this might help

Comment: You might also consider using this library: https://pressurejs.com

Comment: Any code sample?

Answer (score 4):

Using this CSS stops the prompt from firing on any image and won't disable touch events from buttons or markers with images so they still function as normal.

You can still feel the haptic feedback from the touch event when you long press also, you just won't get the prompt/preview.

```css
#root {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

You can disable or enable the touch-callout as you wish in your css

Answer (score 1):

Adding a draggable attribute doesn't work to disable the 3D/force touch. But disabling pointer-events on the  works (on iOS 12.2 at least):

```css
img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Else you have some documentation about force touch in webkit here: [Link to Apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/RespondingtoForceTouchEventsfromJavaScript.html)

Comment: This works to completely disable touch events - but it would be great to be able to just stop the preview

Comment: I’ve now added an example as an answer which works!

Answer (score 0):

From HTML with [draggable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations) attribute

```html
<img src='yourimage.png' draggable='false'>
```

Or by preventing default action by browser for `dragstart` event. Also by checking touch force.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(el=> {

    el.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        return false; 
    });

    // customize your pressure force
    const force = 0.2; 

    // iOS
    el.addEventListener('touchforcechange', e => {
        if (e.changedTouches[0].force < force) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Standard, Firefox
    el.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
        if (e.targetTouches[0].force < force) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6p95jdy/6/) example

Comment: I was still able to 3D Touch on the image on Mobile Safari on an iPhone X.

Comment: Try to play with `e.changedTouches[0].force`, change comparable value

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your image to a data-url SVG and embed it through the svg tag then you cannot 3D touch it. You can also link to other SVG images through the SVG tag. Here is a w3 schools link on how to use the tag: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp